# cancel Submit code not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a problem with my cancel submit code. 
I have used the javascript code for canceling/stopping the submit function on my page but it's not working properly.

It is working in some point but it's not enough.. I'm looking for a solution to this problem please try to help me..

Here's my code for stopping the submit function..

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
 function mySubmit(evt)
 { 
   evt.preventDefault(); 
   try
   {
    someBug();
   }
   catch (e)
   {
    throw new Error(e.message);
   }
  return false;
  }
 }
</script>
```

And in form

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="return mySubmitFunction()">
```

At first it seems that it's working properly because my page is not blinking or refreshing after I click a button but suddenly I noticed that the page is still refreshing but its not blinking .. look at this screenshot

[image]

Notice that the logo is loading after I click the move to left button? look at the red line with arrowhead ..

So I tried to use the onclientclick function and put the return mySubmitFunction in it but same result

Here is the code

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="&gt;&gt;&gt;" 
                    CssClass="button button-primary" 
onclick="Button2_Click" onclientclick="return mySubmitFunction()" />
```

hope you can help me with this thank you i'm new to javascript ^_^

I'm using ASP.NET C#

Ignore the total data in the screenshot ^_^ I didn't click save that's why its not updating yet..

Comment: you don't have `mySubmitFunction` in your javascript

Comment: it's the same ^_^ though mySubmitFunction it's understood that im calling mySubmit(evt)

Answer (score 0):

Check this Example..specify event in onclick onclick="mySubmitFunction(event)"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a id="myAnchor" onclick="mySubmitFunction(event)" href="http://w3schools.com/">Go to W3Schools.com</a>

<p>The preventDefault() method will prevent the link above from following the URL.</p>

<script>
/*document.getElementById("myAnchor").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
});*/
function mySubmitFunction(event){
alert(event)
event.preventDefault();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the same output vinay anyway thank you for trying ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I see that in the tags you said you use jquery, this can be done easy with jquery instead pure javascript, hre you have an example.
http://codepen.io/xploshioOn/pen/ogJWKp

html

```
<form id="form1">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

jquery

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("asd");
});
```

the alert is just to be sure the function is executing...