# listbox data transfer to another listbox using javascript asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, listbox

Do you know how to transfer data from listbox to another listbox ?
I have made one but it didn't stop submitting although I use a function to stop it from submitting .

You can look at my previous problem in this section
[cancel-submit-code-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158986/cancel-submit-code-not-working/29159300#29159300)

The problem is not yet been solved even though there's few people helped me and I tried all their suggestions and recommendations but I always get the same result so I decided to ask you guys if there is someone who can do this using a javascript .

I tried to use one but it's not working because the function is for  and I'm using LISTBOX so I think that's the reason why since I'm new to ASP.net C# javascript I can't change the code because ... it's not English :-D
hope you can change the code for me?

Here's the code for javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">


 function Listbox_transfer(Listbox_Orig, Listbox_Move) {
     var moved = new Array();
     var count = 0;
     for (var item = 0; item < Listbox_Move.options.length; item++) 
     {
         if (Listbox_Move.options[item].selected) {
             var temp = document.createElement("OPTION");
             temp.text = Listbox_Move.options[item].text;
             temp.value = Listbox_Move.options[item].value;


             var index = 0;
             var currOpn;

             while (index < Listbox_Orig.options.length && temp.text > Listbox_Orig.options[index].text)
             {
                 index++;
             }
             if (index < Listbox_Orig.options.length) 
             {
                 currOpn = Listbox_Orig.options[index];
             }


             else 
             {
                 currOpn = null;
             }
             try 
             {
                 Listbox_Orig.Listbox_transfer(temp, currOpn);
             }

             catch (ex) 
             {
                 Listbox_Orig.Listbox_transfer(temp, index);
             }
             moved[count] = Listbox_Move.options[item].value;
             count++;
         }
     }
     if (moved.length > 0) 
     {
         remove(Listbox_Move, moved);
     }

 }

 function remove(Listbox_OrigRemoveFrom, items) 
 {
     for (element in items) {
         var index = 0;
         while (index < Listbox_OrigRemoveFrom.options.length &&
            Listbox_OrigRemoveFrom.options[index].value != items[element]) 
            {
             index++;
         }
         Listbox_OrigRemoveFrom.remove(index);
     }
 }
 function addAll(Listbox_Orig, Listbox_Move) 
 {
     var moved = new Array();
     var count = 0;
     for (var item = 0; item < Listbox_Move.options.length; item++) 
     {
         var temp = document.createElement("OPTION");
         temp.text = Listbox_Move.options[item].text;
         temp.value = Listbox_Move.options[item].value;


         var index = 0;
         var currOpn;


         while (index < Listbox_Orig.options.length && temp.text > Listbox_Orig.options[index].text) {


             index++;

         }


         if (index < Listbox_Orig.options.length) {


             currOpn = Listbox_Orig.options[index];
         }


         else {
             currOpn = null;
         }

         try {
             Listbox_Orig.Listbox_transfer(temp, currOpn);

         }
         catch (ex) {
             Listbox_Orig.Listbox_transfer(temp, index);

         }
     }
     removeAll(Listbox_Move);

 }
 function removeAll(list) {
     for (var count = list.options.length; count >= 0; count--) {
         list.remove(count);
     }
 }
 function selectAll(Listbox_OrigSelect1, Listbox_OrigSelect2) {
     for (var count = 0; count < Listbox_OrigSelect1.options.length; count++) {
         Listbox_OrigSelect1.options[count].selected = true;

     }
     for (var count = 0; count < Listbox_OrigSelect2.options.length; count++) {


         Listbox_OrigSelect2.options[count].selected = true;

     }

 }
```

I'm using input buttons

```
<input id="toTheRightButton" type="button" value=">>>" class="button button-primary" onclick="Listbox_transfer(this.form.ListBox3, this.form.ListBox2)"/>
```

Now here's the whole code of the demo that I tried to copy

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lisbox Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Listbox.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <table style="text-align: center" border="0">
            <tr><td><strong>List 1:</strong><br/>
                    <select size="15" name="list1[]" id="list1" style="width: 350px" multiple="multiple">
                        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
                        <option value="5">Option 5</option>
                        <option value="6">Option 6</option>
                    </select></td>
                <td>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="button" value=">>" onClick="add(this.form.list2, this.form.list1)"/>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <input type="button" value="<<" onClick="add(this.form.list1, this.form.list2)"/>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <input type="button" value="All >>" onClick="addAll(this.form.list2, this.form.list1)"/>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <input type="button" value="All <<" onClick="addAll(this.form.list1, this.form.list2)"/>
                    </td>
                <td><strong>List 2:</strong><br/>
                    <select size="15" name="list2[]" id="list2" style="width: 350px" multiple="multiple">
                    </select></td></tr>
        </table>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p><select name="list3" size="14" multiple>
        <option value="0">selection1</option></select>&nbsp;</p>
    </form>
</body>
```

As you can see the code is for option list .. not for listbox for asp.net :-(
hope you can help me thank you .

Answer (score 1):

Following function is for single item. you can modify it for all items and also make it single by passing listbox id as parameter:

```
 function Add() {
                var selectedItem = $("#lbAvailable > option:selected");

                if (selectedItem.length > 0) {
                    selectedItem.remove().appendTo("#lbSelected");

                    $("#lbAvailable option:first-child").attr("selected", true);
                    $("#lbSelected option:last-child").attr("selected", true);
                }
                else {
                    alert("Select item");
                }
            }

    function Remove() {
                var selectedItem = $("#lbSelected > option:selected");

                if (selectedItem.length > 0) {
                    selectedItem.remove().appendTo("#lbAvailable");

                    $("#lbAvailable option:first-child").attr("selected", true);
                    $("#lbSelected option:last-child").attr("selected", true);
                }
                else {
                    alert("Select item");
                }
            }

 function AddAll() {
            $("#lbAvailable option").each(function () {
                this.remove().appendTo("#lbSelected");
            });
        }

 function RemoveAll() {
            $("#lbSelected option").each(function () {
                this.remove().appendTo("#lbAvailable");
            });
        }
```